# Can I automatically add a filter to a MongoEngine query in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using MongoEngine with Django and I want to add a default filter on all queries that retrieve data, as well as some further logging.  MongoEngine has signals, but does not appear to have any signal for pre-query.  Am I missing something or can anyone recommend an elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

After some further research I can use the custom query sets provided by MongoEngine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet)
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)
        # custom filtering here
        #
        # 
        return queryset
```

then use this class a parent class of all other ViewSet classes you define.

Alternatively (but less clean) you could use the same method but with the `get_queryset()` function.

If you don't want to create a base `ViewSet` class for your `ViewSet` classes. You can overload the `get_queryset()` or better the `filter_queryset()` in each ViewSet class you want to add that functionality to.